# Can I make a video from snapshots of the contents of a CANVAS element?

Tags: html, video, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

I've written an HTML5 application that computes graphs at runtime and displays them in a `canvas` element.

I think that the answer to this question is probably "no", but I would like to know for sure if there is some way of programming my HTML5 application to take a series of these images and turn them into a video file, like an mpeg, for example.

In other words, I understand that HTML5 provides the `video` tag to embed videos in a web page, but can it be used to create videos at run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `video` element is play only (decoding)--it doesn't do encoding.

But...

If your user's browser supports `WebM` (modern versions of Chrome,Opera,FF,IE) then you can use WHAMMY to encode a .webm video file on the client-side. Here's a blog post by its creator, antimatter15:

http://antimatter15.com/wp/2012/08/whammy-a-real-time-javascript-webm-encoder/

Coincidentally, antimatter15 also created a client-side .gif encoder.  If you are just stringing together a limited number of images you might consider an animated .gif instead of encoding a whole video.  Here is antimatter15's code to copy a series of canvas drawings into an animated .gif:

https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I am familiar with animated gifs, but for my project, it would be awesome to be able to make videos.